# cookies required in FBConnect in android?

Tags: android, facebook, fbconnect

In My FBLoginActivity there is a error message "cookies required" with yellow background has shown. how to remove it or how can i rectify it?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
            settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            settings.setSaveFormData(false);
            settings.setSavePassword(false);
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance()
            CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
            cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
```

put breakpoints and see if you have cookies