# Android Facebook SDK Error - Missing Cookie

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

Ny android application posts messages to the user's Facebook wall. It was working fine before until it randomly stopped working. Looking at the LogCat in Eclipse, I am getting this message:

03-01 12:02:53.599: DEBUG/Facebook-WebView(15156): Redirect URL: fbconnect://success/?error_code=110&error_msg=Missing+user+cookie+%28to+validate+session+user%29

How can I obtain the cookie? Also, was it there before when the FB stuff was working ?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it was this guy :

[image]

But probably not. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790742/cookies-required-in-fbconnect-in-android/2790787#2790787)

---

This probably happens when Facebook logs out, and the cookie is cleared. However you're using the old access token. Which isn't valid. So login again and get a new access token

Comment: hahaha that's made my day! although my Facebok stuff is built into the app and not using a browser - Will the info on that link you provided still do the same trick ?

Comment: I'm not an android programmer actualy and can not tell if the link is usefull or not, but upvote for the sence of humor!!!! :)